# Run A Query and Update the Results in MySql

Tags: mysql

Please forgive the lack of formatting!!!
  For some reason I can't figure out how to make it show up
   pretty like everyone elses...

Long time roamer, first time poster.  I'm a newb to MySql and I'm having trouble understanding why the following code doesn't work.

```
 UPDATE CUSTOMER_T

  SET Cust_Status = 'INACTIVE'

  WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT Cust_No, Cust_Last_Name, Cust_Status

FROM CUSTOMER_T NATURAL JOIN BILLING_T

WHERE BILLING_T.Cust_No = BILLING_T.Cust_No

AND (DATEDIFF(BILLING_T.Billing_Due_Date, BILLING_T.Billing_Date_Paid) < (-14)

AND CUSTOMER_T.Cust_Status = "ACTIVE") 

OR (CUSTOMER_T.Cust_Status = "ACTIVE"

AND BILLING_T.Billing_Date_Paid IS NULL));
```

What I'm trying to do is find anyone whose status is ACTIVE AND their bill is more than 14 days late

OR they are ACTIVE AND they have a NULL status for their Billing_Date_Paid field.

Then when I find them, I want to UPDATE their Cust_Status to be "INACTIVE".

If I simply run the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Cust_No, Cust_Last_Name, Cust_Status
FROM CUSTOMER_T NATURAL JOIN BILLING_T
     WHERE BILLING_T.Cust_No = BILLING_T.Cust_No
     AND (DATEDIFF(BILLING_T.Billing_Due_Date, BILLING_T.Billing_Date_Paid) < (-14)
     AND CUSTOMER_T.Cust_Status = "ACTIVE") 
        OR (CUSTOMER_T.Cust_Status = "ACTIVE"
            AND BILLING_T.Billing_Date_Paid IS NULL);
```

Then I can pinpoint the people I'm looking for.  However, whenever I try to incorporate this code into an UPDATE statment (the first bit of code I posted) I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Comment: How are is the billing and customer tables related? Is there only one row in the billing table per customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do a `JOIN` in the update like so:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER_T a
INNER JOIN BILLING_T b ON 
    a.Cust_No = b.Cust_No AND 
    a.Cust_Status = 'ACTIVE' AND 
    (
        b.Billing_Date_Paid IS NULL OR
        DATEDIFF(b.Billing_Due_Date, b.Billing_Date_Paid) < -14
    )
SET a.Cust_Status = 'INACTIVE'
```

Comment: Zane - Thanks for the assist!  Your code does work.  Although, I'm still trying to understand exactly what it is doing. So you're giving Customer_T and Billing_T aliases correct?  Can you explain to me why that is necessary.  I honestly don't know and maybe if I can understand the point of it, then the rest of the code will make more sense to me.   Thanks again for responding so quickly!!!  ALSO, why won't this damn text box let me use the ENTER key???   :)